# Drush restore to proper folder level

Tags: drush, backups

Before working on a site, I take a quick dump of a site via `drush arb --destination=/var/backup/latest.tgz --overwrite` from the root level `/var/www/html`.

However, on the rare occasion that I need to restore via `drush arr ../backup/latest.rgz --overwrite`, I end up with a restored database but the file structure is written to `/var/www/html/html`.

Would `drush arr ../backup/latest.rgz --overwrite --destination=/var/www/` solve this issue? Do I just continue to muddle through with`mv /var/www/html/html* /var/www/html`?

How can I get drush to write to the actual root level for the default drupal site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the --destination flag surely works to say where. I'm not quite sure if the outcome would be a mix of the former and the latter system though. Probably the writing does not delete the old files. It would be safer to delete them manually prior to archive recover.